# Большая и маленькая буква

Tags: прописная-строчная

> мемориальная доска памяти

*доска* - с прописной или строчной буквы? Спасибо.

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

мемориальная доска - оба слова с маленькой (строчной) буквы, слово "памяти" - излишество, мемориальная - это и есть памяти.